# Need to access remote files from Apache server

Tags: apache, jsp, download

I am new to Apache.
I am running apache tomcat in windows and using JSP as the server side language.

I have a page containing links to the files (different machine) as below:

```html
<a href="file:///\\APP-XP3\D\SQLEVAL\books\movies\TheButterflyEffec(2004).avi">TheButterflyEffec(2004).avi</a>
<a href="file:///\\APP-XP1\D\SQLEVAL\books\movies\Superbad.avi">Superbad.avi</a>
```

Why `OnClick`, `saveAs` is not working?
It is working if i save the page locally.
Do I need to configure anything in `server.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

If the files are loaded on the machine running the apache then you need to look of two thinghs...

1. Put the files in a directory inside the apache root directory
2. In the `<a href` specify the file location with the ip address of it 
   (i.e. if your apache is on a machine with IP 192.XXX.XXX.XX then give the a href as follows

> <
>   a
>   href='http://192.XXX.XXX.XX/folderWherefilesare/filename'>
>   filename < / a>

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the browser look for those files on the local visitor machine, not on the server.

You have to build "proxy" code with server side language like PHP that will get file name as parameter, e.g. `Download.php?file=TheButterflyEffec(2004).avi` then read the file from the **server** disk and send the file contents to the browser.

If you're using PHP indeed, here is an article describing what you can do:
http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/forcedownload.html

Otherwise let us know what server side language you can use and retag your question according to this.

Comment: I am using jsp . Is it possible to do it in jsp ?

Comment: @Anbu sure it's possible.. not personally familiar with JSP but Google is, here is [decent article](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=10646) - what you need is *Solution 2* (shove the bytes down the response stream) and remember the content type should be something like `video/avi`

Comment: I have also added proper tags so hopefully someone familiar with JSP and file download will come along with more details if you need. :)

Comment: Hi @Shadow Wizard  thanks for the reply. I saw the given link . In my case the file is present in some other machine. What to do ?

Comment: @Anbu instead of file path like `C:\myfolder\file.avi` just give what you posted originally: `\\APP-XP1\D\SQLEVAL\books\movies\Superbad.avi` and make sure the permissions are correct. To find out more either Google or start new question, wasn't able to find by quick search this time sorry.